# How do I choose a groff macro package?

Tags: groff

I want to try a classic groff macro package for structured technical documents as a replacement for the arguably more complex LaTeX and DocBook.

I understand `ms` was the earliest macro package, and `mm` and `me` came later. How do I choose between `ms`, `mm` or `me`?

What problems were `mm` and `me` trying to solve over `ms`? How do I choose between `mm` or `me` should `ms` be too simple?

Answer (score 4):

I applaud your use of old school text processing. But I'm a bit of a dinosaur.

`groff` has a command line flag "-m" so for the "ms" macros, you'd do this:

```
groff -m ms ....
```

That said, I don't recall a lot of functional difference between `mm` and `me`. I kept my resume in `groff` until very recently, and apparently, I found the "ms" macro package to be entirely sufficient. I did write a couple of macros I wrote in low-level direct `groff` commands to differentiate between major projects I worked on at a long-running corporate job.

Answer (score 3):

You can look through `man groff_mm`, or the actual macro definition file (`/usr/share/groff/*/tmac/m.tmac`) 
to see that the **mm** macros are by far the larger, and more complete of the three original troff packages.  However, they have all been overtaken by the gnu [**mom** macro package](http://www.schaffter.ca/mom/momdoc/docprocessing.html) developed specially for groff and postscript/pdf output.

If you are interested in a clean, easy-to-read, markup language you should also look at [restructuredtext](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/introduction.html) and especially the [sphinx tool](http://sphinx-doc.org/index.html) that uses it.